# How do I filter out memberships (by relationship)?

Tags: civimember, reports

I have a report that generates a list of members who need to be called to renew, however I want to remove from the report all those with a Membership Type: Annual Member (by relationship). Any suggestions? Thanks!

Civi 5.3.1 on Drupal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use 'Membership Owner ID' filter under filters tab of report.

When you set 'Membership Owner ID' as 'is empty(NULL)' it will show all the primary membership owners that is membership not created by relationship
[image]

When you set 'Membership Owner ID' as 'is not empty(NULL)' it will show all the secondary membership owners that is membership created by relationship membership
[image]

PS: Don't miss to filter Membership type ;)

HTH

Pradeep